# How to I keep the user signed in with Flutter Firebase Authentication and Apple Sign In?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

I'm using `sign_in_with_apple` with Firebase Authentication and have been able to successfully sign in, get the user credentials, and use the firebase authenticated user info to upload data to Firebase Storage.

My issue is that the after restarting the app, the user is not signed in and has to sign in again every time.

I've been using Google Sign In as well, and I'm able to use `_googleSignIn.signInSilently()` to sign in on restart, but I haven't seen anything like that for the Apple sign in.

Is there a method I'm missing? Do I need to save the credentials?

I'm using the `sign_in_with_apple` and `google_sign_in` packages.
I use the `handleGoogleSignIn` to sign in with Google, then run the  the `initHelper` to handle changes to sign in, and silently sign in after the user signed in once. I don't manually save credentials or a token.
I use the `appleSignIn` method to let a user sign in for the first time, but I'm new to this and don't understand how I can persist the sign in.

I'm clearly new to this and have been unable to find tutorials or help, any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated

```dart
Future<void> initHelper(SharedPreferencesHelper sharedPrefs) async {
    _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount account) async {
      currentGoogleUser = account;
      if (currentGoogleUser != null) {
        // Obtain the auth details from the request
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await account.authentication;

        // Create a new credential
        final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
          idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
        );
        UserCredential firebaseCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

        newUser(
            userId: currentGoogleUser.id,
            userName: currentGoogleUser.displayName,
            userEmail: currentGoogleUser.email,
            firebaseId: firebaseCredential.user.uid);
      } else {
        user = null;
      }
      notifyListeners();
    });

    await _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
}

 Future<String> handleGoogleSignIn(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      GoogleSignInAccount account = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (account == null) {}
      return account == null ? S.of(context).cancel : null;
    } catch (error) {
      return error.toString();
    }
  }

Future<bool> appleSignIn() async {
    bool success = false;

    final rawNonce = generateNonce();
    final nonce = sha256ofString(rawNonce);

    final credential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
      scopes: [
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
      ],
      nonce: nonce,
    );

    // Create an `OAuthCredential` from the credential returned by Apple.
    final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential(
      idToken: credential.identityToken,
      rawNonce: rawNonce,
    );

    UserCredential firebaseCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential);

    if (credential != null) {
      success = true;
      newUser(
          userType: appleType,
          userId: credential.userIdentifier,
          firebaseId: firebaseCredential.user.uid);
      notifyListeners();
    }

    return success;
  }
```

Comment: "My issue is that the after restarting the app, the user is not signed in and has to sign in again every time." --- "Is there a method I'm missing? Do I need to save the credentials?" It is impossible for us to answer the question without seeing the [minimal, complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Maybe a bit late, but out of curiosity, is there a reason you're using the `sign_in_with_apple` package as opposed to just using the `AppleAuthProvider` as seen in the following example in the FlutterFire repo? https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/example/lib/auth.dart#L546. I'm not sure when exactly the functionality was added by the FlutterFire team, but I do see the commit history indicates the example was updated in 2022 August, so maybe it wasn't available at the time when the question was posted?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that option when I first set this up. Good to know it exists now. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is you are not understanding user authorization flow. After successful logging with Google/Facebook/Apple providers, any type of providers returns a key for you, that key you need to confirm on server side   what going back to providers and checks if this key is valid and belongs to this user. And after all this flow your server should return a token, what your need to save somewhere like [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) and use for requests signing. More detailed read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth).

If your app do not use any server logic, you can just store some bool in [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), and check it on start of your app. Additionally you can store users credentials somewhere I mention before.

If succesfully logined:

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.setBool('isLogined', true);
```

On the start of the app:

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final bool? isLogined = prefs.getBool('isLogined');

if (isLogined == true) {
  // move to the app.
} else {
  // move to the login screen.
}
```

But in this case authorization is useless step what you can just remove from your app.

**UPDATE**

For you case use this code:

```
var currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

if (currentUser != null) {
  // move to main screen
} else {
  // move to auth
}
```

Read more about this [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#user-management).

Comment: Thank you so much for the guidance. I've added my code to make my situation more clear. If I'm understanding correctly, should i save the ```credential.identityToken``` with something like flutter_secure_storage. Then when the app is opened, I check if that token is available, then use it to create a new oauthCredential?

Comment: @u2tall, I'l update my comment for you case.

Comment: Saving "isLoggedIn" is a bad idea. My understanding from reading the official documentation is, we have to use "authorizationCode" to get refresh token from Apple's server, and re-request it periodically, using this refresh token in subsequent requests. This is how we determine that this particular user still wants to be logged in on our app.