# How to SILENTLY sign in with apple in flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

I have built an app in which the users can log in using Google, Email/Password, and Apple, using Firebase Auth.

For the Google Sign in, I get the credentials using

```
final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn(clientId: clientId).signIn();
final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth = await googleUser?.authentication;
final oauthCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
    );
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential);
```

And for the Apple Sign in, I use the `sign_in_with_apple` package as described [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/social/#apple):

```
AuthorizationCredentialAppleID appleCredential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
        scopes: [
          AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
          AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
        ],
        nonce: nonce,
      );
final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential(
        idToken: appleCredential.identityToken,
        rawNonce: rawNonce,
      );
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential);
```

**This works fine so far** for signing in the user after they confirm the login popup.

Now I want to add silent sign in (= sign in with the saved credentials without user interaction) to both Google an Apple.
To do this I save the `oAuthCredential` after successfull login, and when the app is started the next time, I load it and call

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(oAuthCredential);
```

to sign in the user. For Google this works perfectly fine, but on iOS for the Apple Sign In, I get this Firebase Auth error:

```
missing-or-invalid-nonce: Duplicate credential received. Please try again with a new credential.
```

I have googled for ages but haven't found anything helpful. What's the problem here?

Comment: You should start by checking the firebase auth `currentUser` property - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users there should be no need for you to save the oauth credential. Firebase can handle this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71934709) answer and the comment here by @Paulw11, `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` magically all does this for me and I don't have to save any credentials at all.